# How can I insert a hyphen in LaTeX?

Tags: hyperref, hyphenation, links, hyperlink

I have tried everything but I just can't get a proper hyphen inserted into a LaTeX portion.

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
\textit{ABC:} \href{someLink}{A-B-C}
```

I just want the two hyphens between A, B & C to be rendered properly.

However, LaTeX introduces a line break after the second hyphen and that is causing a lot of trouble in the document.

Any possible ways to fix this?

Comment: `\mbox{A-B-C}` ? (Overleaf is not involved here, they run a stadard latex installation)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle hello ! Thanks, this is exactly what i had to do to get the hyphens working ! I appreciate your help

Comment: I needed to give the comment so @egreg could answer, he needs the points:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ahaha ! yes, i noticed now ! he's closing in on a million ! this is pleasantly amusing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general TeX rule, explicit hyphens<sup>1</sup> can be used as a line break point. The second argument to `\href` is suitably processed so it can participate to line breaking, which might be necessary if it consists of several words or a rather long word alone (so spaces can be adjusted and hyphenation is tried for justification).

In order to exclude a hyphen from being used as a line break point, hide it in `\mbox`.

```
\href{someLink}{\mbox{A-B-C}}
```

###### Footnote

<sup><sup>1</sup> To be precise, the character whose character code has the same value as the `\hyphenchar` parameter for the current font.</sup>

Comment: Perfect ! this worked flawlessly ! Thank you so much ! Accepting this as the correct Answer !